# What does hash in IE style mean?

Tags: css

I have a sample CSS that I downloaded that has the entry

```css
#text-align: right;
```

in it.  The comment next to the entry says that this expression justifies it for IE, whereas

text-align: right;

works for Safari and Chrome.  My question:  what is the significance of the hash in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a hack because early versions of IE sucked so badly

Comment: it's a browser hack for old IE versions, but it looks like a bit of a weird thing to hack, seeing as how `text-align:right` works fine in all browsers, including old IE. I could do with a bit more context; ie seeing more of the file, to see what else is being hacked, but my guess is that it's been done by a developer who didn't really know what he was doing and way trying everything to make IE work. I'd be willing to bet tha the site puts IE in quirks mode as well, which is probably the only reason the hacks were needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is something called a "CSS hack" which alters the behavior of IE because it is so terrible and doesn't support the latest CSS definitions. Other browsers will ignore the statement entirely (as if it were a comment) but IE will treat it as `text-align:right;`

Comment: more specifically because old versions of IE were so terrible they didn't support CSS properly. Having said that, `text-align:right` has worked perfectly well in every browser since CSS was first invented, so I can't imagine any reason for wanting to hack this specific style, even for old IE.

Comment: @Spudley I did wonder about that actually, especially since `text-align` is such a basic property